# pushObject not parsing JSON to Ember object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to push data to my model. This model has an array of object called content. The problem is that Ember does not parse it into an Ember object even if I use the pushObject method. This results in my template not updating. Here is the code of the request :

```
Ember.$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'conversations/' + self.get('model').id + '/send',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: new_message,
    success: function(data){
        self.get('model.content.sentMessages').pushObject(data);
    },
    error: function(){

    }
  });
```

**How do you parse JSON response into an ember object?**

EDIT : I am using ember-data

```
App.Conversation = DS.Model.extend({
status: DS.attr(),
readStatus: DS.attr(),
timeAgoElement: DS.attr(),
lastMessage: DS.attr(),
customer: DS.belongsTo('customer'),
user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
content: DS.attr(),
lastReopenedSlug: DS.attr(),

lastReopened: function(){
    return this.get('lastReopenedSlug') === this.get('id');
}.property('lastReopenedSlug', 'id'),

sortedContent: function(){
    if(this.get('content')){
        var content = this.get('content');
        return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
            sortProperties: ['createdAt'],
            sortAscending: true,
            content: content.sentMessages.concat(content.receivedMessages).concat(content.notes).concat(content.assignations).concat(content.statuses)
        });
    }   
}.property('content'),

timeAgoFormated: function(){
    return moment(this.get('timeAgoElement')).fromNow();
}.property('timeAgoElement'),

lastMessageFormated: function(){
    var lastMessage = this.get('lastMessage');
    if(nthOccurrence(lastMessage, ' ', 3) != -1){
        return lastMessage.substr(0, nthOccurrence(lastMessage, ' ', 3)) + "...";
    }
    return lastMessage;
}.property('lastMessage')
});
```

The data returned to the template is the sortedContent, which depends on the content. I noticed that my new data is pushed to the content as I want, but in JSON format instead of Ember Object format, which prevents my template from updating.

Useful template rendering :

```
{{#each elem in model.sortedContent}}
    --display x--
{{/each}}
```

Comment: can you post your template and what your return data looks like? And to clarify, are you actually using Ember Data? If so, post your model relationships as well. pushObject doesn't parse data, it literally just pushes the object into the array. You probably want to do Ember.Object.create(data) first (or use whatever constructor that you're using for the sentMessages models).

Comment: sentMessage isnt a model, it is associated to the conversations' model content. I don't see any reason to create a model for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing data into `content.sentMessages` but the `model.sortedContent` property is only looking at `content` before it recomputes. You might need to also add `content.sentMessages.length` to your `sortedContent` property -

```
sortedContent: function() {
  if (this.get('content')) {
    var content = this.get('content');
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
      sortProperties: ['createdAt'],
      sortAscending: true,
      content: content.sentMessages.concat(content.receivedMessages).concat(content.notes).concat(content.assignations).concat(content.statuses)
    });
  }
}.property('content', 'content.sentMessages.length')
```

Does that work? Also maybe throw a `console.log('whatever')` in `sortedContent:` to see if it's being called when you do your `.pushObject()`

Comment: My sir, you are a genius. I tought that looking at content would look at everything related to it. I was wrong and you were right! This works!

Comment: Ha yeah I think that bites everyone at some point or another.